# Scala: A setter on a singleton object

Tags: scala

My Scala application (an Akka service) has a `PersonBuilder` class

This `PersonBuilder` class has a REST client that retrieves some data, before building the entity.

There should only ever be **one instance** of this `PersonBuilder` in my application at any one time.

Obviously, I could use a `PersonBuilder` object here but the problem is that I want to pass in a mock REST client when running unit tests.

Is invoking a setter on an object considered bad practice in Scala?
If it's done **safely** and guaranteed to only ever happen once then surely it's a technique that could be employed?

Obviously creating a class with an encapsulated REST client could be done as well, but the problem then is I've to pass this `PersonBuilder` class all around my code in the absence of a dependency injection framework.

Are there any conventions around this in Scala at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class PersonBuilder(rest: Rest)
object PersonBuilder extends PersonBuilder(LiveRest)
object TestPersonBuilder extends PersonBuilder(MockRest)
```

If you don't want constructor args, use traits.

```
trait PersonBuilder {
  def rest: Rest
}
object PersonBuilder extends PersonBuilder {
  override val rest = LiveRest
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, I didn't know you could do that

Comment: As a matter of interest what are your thoughts on the Object setter approach?

Comment: @DJ180 If you used a setter, wash your hands thoroughly so the smell of the code doesn't ingrain to your fingers or sleeves, rinse with lots of water, come back to the keyboard and replace with either of the above patterns. :)

Comment: :-) Yes, I agree, it just didn't feel right hence my original question. I guess the 2 concerns I had originally were (1) setters open objects up to mis-use, race conditions etc (2) readability

Comment: I'm not sure this solution solves my problem after all. I still have to pass around a reference to a PersonBuilder in all classes that use it. I guess I need to find a reliable dependency injection framework for my Akka service